# Summing Children of Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, here's a snippet:

```
 [6 - CAMERAS & SUPPLIES] => Array
            (
                [CAMERAS] => Array
                    (
                        [CAMCORDERS] => Array
                            (
                                [ACTION CAMCORDERS] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 70.83
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 401.59
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 53.01
                                    )

                                [STANDARD CAMCORDERS] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 96.09
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 96.09
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 68.21
                                    )
                                [SURVELIANCE] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 84.00
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 84.00
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 26.00
                                    )
                            )
                        [subCAMERAS] => Array
                            (
                                [BIG ZOOM] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 31.66
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 13.68
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 1.47
                                    )
                                [PEGGED CAMERAS] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 13.50
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 5.50
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 5.00
                                    )
                                [POINT-N-SHOOT] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 46.61
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 10.35
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 4.06
                                    )
                                [RUGGED CAMERAS] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 87.04
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 87.04
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 65.20
                                    )

                                [SLR] => Array
                                    (
                                        [total_ty_yest_sales] => 50.19
                                        [total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales] => 9.40
                                        [east_ty_yest_sales] => 1.37
                                    )
                            )
                    )
```

I display the array in a table:

```
6 - CAMERAS & SUPPLIES              --sum--     --sum--     --sum--
    CAMERAS                         --sum--     --sum--     --sum--
         CAMCORDERS                 --sum--     --sum--     --sum--
             ACTION CAMCORDERS      70.83       401.59      53.01 
             STANDARD CAMCORDERS      96.09     96.09       68.21 
             SURVEILLANCE             84.00     84.00       26.00 
        subCAMERAS                     --sum--     --sum--     --sum--
             BIG ZOOM                31.66     13.68         1.47 
             PEGGED CAMERAS         13.50       5.50        5.00 
             POINT-N-SHOOT          46.61       10.35       4.06 
             RUGGED CAMERAS         87.04       87.04       65.20 
             SLR                    50.19       9.40        1.37
```

I want to sum the parents of each portion of the array. i.e. I want to replace "--sum--" with the sum of the children. So... subCameras = big zoom + pegged cameras + point-n-shoot + rugged cameras + slr. Cameras = camcorders + subCameras. etc.

This is what I have for the table:

```
        foreach($group as $gmm => $acctg_dept_nbrs) {
        echo "\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td>" . $gmm . "</td>\n";

        foreach ($acctg_dept_nbrs as $acctg_dept_nbr => $dept_catg_grp_descs) {
            echo "\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding-left: 1em;\">" . $acctg_dept_nbr . "</td>\n";
            $total_acctg_dept_nbr = 0;
            foreach($dept_catg_grp_descs as $dept_catg_grp_desc => $dept_category_descs) {
                echo "\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding-left: 2em;\">" . $dept_catg_grp_desc . "</td>\n";
                $total_dept_catg_grp_desc = 0;
                foreach($dept_category_descs as $dept_category_desc => $dept_subcatg_descs) {
                    echo "\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding-left: 3em;\">" . $dept_category_desc . "</td>\n";
                    $total_dept_category_desc = 0;
                    //$sum = array_sum($dept_subcatg_descs[])
                    foreach($dept_subcatg_descs as $dept_subcatg_desc => $values) {
                        echo "\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td style=\"padding-left: 4em;\">" . $dept_subcatg_desc . "</td>\n";
                        //$total_dept_subcatg_desc = 0;
                        $sum = $values['total_ty_yest_sales'];
                        echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                        $sum = $values['total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales'];
                        echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                        $sum = $values['east_ty_yest_sales'];
                        echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                        //$total_dept_category_desc += $sum;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You sure love to use tab characters ;)

Comment: Could you place a working example of your code at http://phpfiddle.org

Comment: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/ynd-9tz